# windows 10: Weird mouse movement (jumping and circle seen)

Tags: windows-10, mouse, window

I have Dell Inspiron 15z running with Windows 10.  From quite sometime, I am facing mouse jumping & movement issue. When issues appears, I will see circles around screen. This issue appears after sometime using laptop rather appearing immediately. After recent OS updates, it is appearing more frequently; earlier shutdown & restart PC would let me work for couple of hours.

I have removed default touch pad mouse hardware or ensuring it's driver updated but nothing helped. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

**Update:**

1. Sometimes, this issue will be observed when I turn-on laptop first time and won't be able to login. Have to try multiple restart (forceful) to get rid of it.
2. Sometimes, this issue appears after hours of uses. If I have multiple browser tabs open, closing that particular tab will not temporarily will not show that mouse problem. BUT it is surely not related to browser.
3. Multiple restart/shutdown, temporarily helps to get rid of issue.

I am yet to try all solutions provided but this laptop is not covered warranty.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is usually with the touch screen, but I don't know what kind
of operation you did when you "removed default touch pad mouse hardware".
Maybe you should undo what you did and follow the advice below.

The usual advice given by Microsoft is :

**Method 1 - Hardware and Devices troubleshooter**

- Type troubleshooting in the search bar
- Select Troubleshooting
- Select View all on the top left corner
- Click on Hardware and Devices
- Follow the on-screen instructions to run the troubleshooter
- If the issue persists, move to the next method.

**Method 2 - reinstall the Human Interface Devices driver**

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and select Device Manager
- Search for Human Interface Devices and expand it
- Right click on the Touchscreen and select Uninstall
- Restart your computer to install the Windows drivers.

If this does not help :

- Try another mouse.
- Try closing and opening the lid whenever it happens.
  If this solves the problem keep on doing it for a few days - some people
  report that this solved their problem.
- [Perform a clean boot in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows)
  and if this helps then the problem might be caused by some installed
  application.
- If the computer is still under warranty, ask for a touch screen replacement.
  If they refuse let them fix the problem themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this is a motherboard chipset soldering / heating issue. The north bridge of the mobo is responsible for video rendering, and due to overheating (and cold soldering) the chip starts acting weirdly. There's nothing much you can do at home, better diagnostics can be done in the lab (and chip replacement if possible). Check if the laptop is still under warranty, and consider replacing the motherboard. Just to make sure - if you have a spare hdd drive you can try and install clean OS, and then run some video check like 3dmark. If it fails / starts to glitch / gets stuck - chipset.

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have that issue not 5 minutes ago. So I did a cleanboot, looked for any recently installed unknown programs, ran a scan, the usual etc. Nothing helped. Then I thought about the Windows update I was due to DL  and when I updated the PC it went away. In detail, my issue was that I had 3 strange circles at the top right of my screen and it seemed, an "extra" cursor arrow hovering above one of the circles. It was interfering with my main cursor, I could not execute any commands or click anything without my cursor jumping around and flashing. Like I said as soon as I downloaded the Windows update (during restart or reboot) it cleared the circles and I am having no issue as of yet. I posted this for ha ha's and possibly to help someone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem with the erratic mouse pointer. I am very interested to read the comments by Mr Safronov about possible overheating affecting the video. I have noticed that the issue is definitely worse the more the laptop is loaded with tasks to do, also that stopping to change some settings almost always results in some temporary improvement. Perhaps it's the act of stopping which allows it to cool down. I don't know if I have to change the motherboard to fix this, or if something can be done with the existing one.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1191860)